# Is it possible to run Java Code written on Bluej on a computer?

Tags: java

I have written a program in Blue J for a client and would like to give the client some steps as to how he can use the product. I tried using Command Prompt, but somehow, the Files which were meant to store data are not being accessed by the program. The program has two classes and uses File Handling. There are no bugs in the program as it works perfectly well in Blue J environment.

Comment: Could you be more specific? I mean what error you get. or which part of your code is causing the problem.

Comment: Package your java project as a JAR file. Don't just give someone Java files and expect them to know what to do with it or figure out how to use them

Comment: Do you need any other help?

Answer (score 2):

shrey

if you want to deploy the entire code using jar then make sure that codes like `System.out.println();` are replaced by their graphical counterparts or else you won't be able to see anything that goes it the background.

To use jar, BlueJ is good enough. It works like a charm. The only thing your client needs is a JRE and he can use your app.

Compile------->Project--------->Create Jar File

and select the code. You are done.

Provide a compatible JRE along with the jar to your client if he doesn't have one.